# Срабатывание скрипта если ширина экрана меньше 767

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, прокрутка

Скролл должен срабатывать когда ширина экрана меньше или равно `767px`, если больше – скрипт не должен срабатывать.

```js
function windowSize(){
    if ($(window).width() <= '767'){
        $('#test').on('click', function(e) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: $('.test2').offset().top + "px"
              }, {
                duration: 1E3
            });
          });
    } else {
    }
}
```

```css
.test2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 1000px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="test">
  Кнопка скролла которая срабатывает если ширина меньше 767
</button>

<div class="test2"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А проблема у вас в чем? Когда ширина менше 995 у вас кнопка сама должна срабатывать или появиться?

Comment: @JuniorCoder Проблема в том что код который написан в функции "$('#test').on...." должен срабатывать только когда ширина меньше 767, а когда выше код просто не активный и при нажатии на кнопку нечего не происходит. Не получается у меня функцию данную написать.

Comment: Так поместите if ($(window).width() <= '767')  внутрь кнопки ,получиться что когда клик на кпопку и условия true , код будет работать иначе нет!

Comment: @JuniorCoder Просто помимо данного кода на ней есть и другие события. А именно добавление класса в принципе.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Comment: @Adrug не помогло к сожалению.

Answer (score 2):

Решение на нативном JS:

```js
// Сперва пишем функцию с условием:
function scrollFunctions() {

    var btn = document.getElementById('test');
    // Вызываем скролл по клику при выполнении условия
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 767) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', scrollTop);
    } 
    // Убираем скролл по клику при не выполнении условия
    else{ 
        btn.removeEventListener('click', scrollTop);
    }
}

// Потом функцию для самого скролла:
function scrollTop(){
    window.scrollTo({
        top: 400,
        behavior: 'smooth',
    });
}

// А потом вызываем нашу функцию с условием, 
// которая при выполнении условия вызывает функцию со скроллом:
window.addEventListener('load', scrollFunctions);
window.addEventListener('resize', scrollFunctions);
```

```css
#body {
  height: 1000px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id='body'>
  <button id='test'>Click to scroll</button>
</div>
```